# Dialogos complexo com Watson

Tags: node.js, chatbot, watson

Comecei a desenvolver um `chatbot` utilizando o `watson`, achei surpreendente e simples de implantar. Porem fiquei com algumas duvidas de como fazer e se é possivel (vi em alguns `chatbot`).

Um exemplo é, utilizando o `conversation` eu consigo definir `#intenções`, `@entidades` e `dialogos`. Porem, como funcionaria o processo de dar opções? Um exemplo, fiz uma pergunta "Qual a melhor cerveja?" e ele me responderia algo assim "Existem muitas cervejas, mas uma lista com 5 para você" e assim lista-se elas em lista. e que eu pudesse clicar e seguir com o dialogo e etc. Já vi isso em alguns `chatbot`, mas não vi como fazer esse tipo de coisa com o watson.

Outra coisa é, é possivel interagir com um Back-End? Ex: "Contas vencidas", e meu back iria consultar no banco e retornar as contas vencidadas.

Fiquei bem confuso diante esse topicos. E, por ultimo, o Watson é a melhor opção para desenvolver um `chatbot`?

Comment: Dá para tirar umas seis boas perguntas dessa pergunta, mas da forma como está escrita deveria ser fechada parte como muito ampla, tem muita coisa para se falar sobre o assunto outra parte como baseada em opiniões.